# How do I get this simple layout for UITableView header to work using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm ashamed to post this, but I'm becoming desperate.

I'm a noob when it comes to AutoLayout.  That's mostly because my app has nearly 60 different screens in it.  Why change what's working?  Anyway, I don't use XIBs/NIBs/Storyboards, because anytime I'd need to make an application-wide UI change, I'd have to fix a bunch of things.  Instead, I have my own set of UIViewController subclasses.  One of them just has a UITableView much like UITableViewController.  I can crank out UITableViews in my sleep.

I have a new screen that needs a couple of buttons inside the table view's header.  I'm trying to get better with AutoLayout, so I try to use it whenever I can.  Without further narrative, here's a very short self-contained example.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rows;
@end

@implementation TestViewController
- (void) loadView {
    UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [tv setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [tv setDelegate:self];
    [tv setDataSource:self];
    [self setView:tv];

    UIView *tableHeader = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [tableHeader setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [tv setTableHeaderView:tableHeader];

    UIButton *selectProfileButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [selectProfileButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [selectProfileButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [selectProfileButton setTitle:@"Select Profile..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tableHeader addSubview:selectProfileButton];

    UIButton *editProfileButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [editProfileButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [editProfileButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EditAccessoryIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tableHeader addSubview:editProfileButton];


    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 10, 5, 5);

    // select button in NW corner
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:selectProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:padding.top]];
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:selectProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:padding.left]];
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:selectProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-padding.bottom]];

    // edit button in NE corner
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:editProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:padding.top]];
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:editProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-padding.right]];
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:editProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:tableHeader attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-padding.bottom]];

    // spacing between buttons
    [tableHeader addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:selectProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                               toItem:editProfileButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:-10.0]];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [[self rows] count]; }

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[self rows] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [test setRows:@[@"1", @"2", @"3"]];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:test];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Unfortunately, at runtime I get this:

```
2014-07-11 13:18:48.502 TestTableHeader[9478:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
2014-07-11 13:18:48.505 TestTableHeader[9478:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ed1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156c8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017ed048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x0114c4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x0029ba38 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 567
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157e82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    6   QuartzCore                          0x03c5845a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    7   QuartzCore                          0x03c4c244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    8   QuartzCore                          0x03c583a5 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
    9   UIKit                               0x0035dae3 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
    10  UIKit                               0x00273aa7 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
    11  UIKit                               0x00272646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    12  UIKit                               0x00272518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    13  UIKit                               0x002725a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    14  UIKit                               0x0027163a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    15  UIKit                               0x0027159c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    16  UIKit                               0x002722f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    17  UIKit                               0x002758e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    18  UIKit                               0x0034fb77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    19  UIKit                               0x0026b474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
    20  UIKit                               0x0026b5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    21  UIKit                               0x0026b86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    22  UIKit                               0x002763c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    23  TestTableHeader                     0x00002dfa -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 890
    24  UIKit                               0x0022614f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    25  UIKit                               0x00226aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
    26  UIKit                               0x0022b667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    27  UIKit                               0x0023ff92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    28  UIKit                               0x00240555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    29  UIKit                               0x0022d250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x037e2f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x037e2a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x01768ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x017689db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0179368c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x017929d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x017927eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  UIKit                               0x0022ad9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    38  UIKit                               0x0022cf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    39  TestTableHeader                     0x00002fed main + 141
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e34701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

From what I've read, this means I'm missing a constraint.  UIButtons have an intrinsic size, so I only need to set their position.  The container UIView will be sized by the UITableView, so there's nothing to do there.  (I even tried setting the height for giggles--I didn't giggle.)

Where have I screwed up?

Thanks!

**Updated example code and stack to provide short self-contained example.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I think it's not caused by missing constraints. It's rather because `UITableView` apparently doesn't handle headers / footers with autolayout properly. The workaround that works for me is to set frame using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` method:

```
//initialize tableHeader, add subviews and constraints
CGSize size = [tableHeader systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
tableHeader.frame = (CGRect){.origin = CGPointZero, .size = size};

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader;
```

Note that I **didn't** set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Also, it seems you haven't added all the needed constraints. You only position the buttons, but your tableHeader doesn't know how  to calculate its *own* width and height. You probably need to make `selectProfileButton`'s (or the other button's) bottom equal to `tableHeader`'s bottom and add a (minimum) horizontal spacing between buttons.
Also, as far as I remember, UITableView will extend `tableHeader`'s width to its own regardless of any constraints.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't tried the systemLayoutSizeFittingSize thing yet.  I did try adding more constraints as you suggested and they haven't yielded any improvement.  I will try setting the frame next.

Comment: Setting the frame did not help.  :(

Comment: Still the same crash? Or the header doesn't display correctly?

Comment: Not sure if it's the very same crash, but it did crash. I'll check on it soon.

Comment: I gave up.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ungave up.  The real kicker is to not set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints (just as you said).  I kept getting a 0,0 from the systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: call so I just manually set the tableHeader frame to CGRectMake(0,0,0,40).